# Excel IF G1=A2 (date) and G2=B2 (type) and G3=C2 (item no) then return the price of D2 in G4 but if D2 is blank ret the price from next prev date D3

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I need to write an statement IF VALUE 1 equals A2 and VALUE 2 equals B2 and VALUE 3 equals C2 then return the price of D2 but if D2 is blank return the price from the previous date of A2. So the example below If VALUE 1 is 6/30/2012 and VALUE 2 is Sweater and VALUE 3 is SW123456 the results will be 19.00 (from 3/31/2012) since 6/30/2012 is blank.

TABLE example:

## A           B           C             D

#### DATE      TYPE        ITEM NO     PRICE

6/30/2012     Sweater     SW123456
3/31/2012     Sweater     SW123456     19.00

VALUE 1:  6/30/2012
VALUE 2:  Sweater
VALUE 3:  SW123456
RESULTS:

Comment: Forgot to change the cell references:  Excel IF A5=A2 (date) and A6=B2 (type) and A7=C2 (item no) then return the price of D2 in A8 but if D2 is blank ret the price from next prev date D3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(MAX(IF($A:$A<G1,IF($B:$B=G2,IF($C:$C=G3,IF($D:$D<>"",$A:$A))))),IF($A:$A<G1,IF($B:$B=G2,IF($C:$C=G3,IF($D:$D<>"",$A:$A)))),0))
```

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

I set up my sheet like this, so you can understand the references:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. How can I set it up so the range it's using is the whole column (of course I will move A6:B9 to another column) like $D:$D?

Comment: You can just change all the references to full column like you have, but beware that will increase the time of calculation.  It is better to set actual range. but try it if you are okay with the calculation times it will work.  So yes you would put `$D:$D` and so forth for all the columns.

Comment: @user5784986 if you are going with this one please mark as correct by hitting the green check by the answer.

Comment: Sorry but I was just told I need to get the result of the previous date and if that is blank go to the next previous date. How do I do that?

Comment: @user5784986 my formula will find the max date that is less than or equal to than the one in Value 1 that has a value in Price.  So it should work.  It will bring the next closest date to the one in Value 1 that has a price.  See edit.  I adjusted it to be full column.  As you can see it brought back the 5/5/2012 date because it is the closest to the null date

Comment: @user5784986 the other formula should do the same thing.  Nope never mind it finds the next one in order.  you would need to sort on column A to make it work.

Comment: I'm using the above formula you created first. How do I adjust it for that? Can you show how you did it on the spreadsheet?

Comment: @user5784986 I replaced the formula with the one I am using in the picture.

Comment: How do I explain what I need. Let's add data on D2 as 5.00. The result should be 19.00 (D3). Or if D3 is blank the result should be 20.00 (D4). Is this making sense?

Comment: @user5784986 I am still not understanding.  If you put the value in D2 of 5.00 that is what the Results will be.  So the criteria is changing.  Why would it be 19.00?  The logic does not follow.  Try explaining the whole picture again.

Comment: I need to write an statement IF VALUE 1 (6/30/2012) equals A2 and VALUE 2 equals B2 and VALUE 3 equals C2 then return the price of the previous date (3/31/2012) of value 1. But if that previous date (3/31/2012) price is blank then get the price from the next previous date.

Comment: @user5784986 So what you really want is for the precious date not equal but less than.  See edit.  It will find the precious date.

Comment: I'm not getting the correct results. I copied and pasted the formula. =INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(MAX(IF($A:$A<=G1,IF($B:$B=G2,IF($C:$C=G3,IF($D:$D<>"",$A:$A))))),IF($A:$A<=G1,IF($B:$B=G2,IF($C:$C=G3,IF($D:$D<>"",$A:$A)))),0))

Comment: @user5784986 I forgot to hit the save button sorry, See edit

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Deeply appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've moved your inputs (VALUE 1 etc) and RESULT to G1:G4, so we can use the whole range A:D for the data.

First, you want to look up the latest date before or on the date you're looking at that has a match for all other criteria and has a price that's not empty. You can do this by using the formula:

```
= MAX( INDEX( A:A, MATCH( 1,  (A:A   <= G1 ) * ( B:B = G2 ) * ( C:C = G3 ) * ( NOT( ISBLANK( D:D ) ) ), 0 ) ) )
```

This is an array formula, so you should confirm by ctrl+shift+Enter rather than just Enter. In your example, this should give you 3/31/12. For the sake of argument, let's call this "myDate".

Secondly, you need to find the price which matches the VALUE 2 and VALUE 3, as well as the date you've just found. This can be done as follows:

```
= INDEX( D:D, MATCH( 1, ( A:A = myDate ) * ( B:B  = G2 ) * ( C:C  = G3 ), 0 ) )
```

This is again an array formula. Now, all we need to do is replace "myDate" with the first function, which gives us:

```
= INDEX( D:D, MATCH( 1, ( A:A = MAX( INDEX( A:A, MATCH( 1, ( A:A   <= G1 ) * ( B:B  = G2 ) * ( C:C   = G3 ) * ( NOT( ISBLANK( D:D  ) ) ), 0 ) ) ) ) * ( B:B  = G2 ) * ( C:C  = G3 ), 0 ) )
```

Again, this is an array formula, so confirm with ctrl+shift+Enter.

Comment: Thank you. You're very helpful.

Comment: Just an FYI.  The OP is back.  The formula you provided is not quite what he/she wants.  Your formula finds the next row that satisfies the conditions.  The OP wants the next date and the dates are not always sorted properly.

Comment: = INDEX( D:D, MATCH( 1, ( A:A = **MAX( INDEX( A:A, MATCH( 1, ( A:A   <= G1 )** * ( B:B  = G2 ) * ( C:C   = G3 ) * ( NOT( ISBLANK( D:D  ) ) ), 0 ) ) ) ) * ( B:B  = G2 ) * ( C:C  = G3 ), 0 ) ) Looks for the last date before or on the selected date that has a price. That should do the trick, no?